# How to display the FAQ Archive page in my menu

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, custom-post-type-archives

I'm using the Wordpress standard menu. I've also created a custom post type.

I'd like to include my custom post type archive page (the all item) in the Appearance -> Menus, but so far I can select only the individual items.

Any idea how I can do this?
THanks

Comment: You have a couple of options here, either creating a custom menu, or actually creating a normal page template (some think it is a bit overrated, lol). For the page template option, check out my [Q&A here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140181/dynamic-page-php-template-for-custom-post-types/140182#140182). Hope you find it useful. If so, an upvote will be appreciated, lol.

Comment: That doesn't sound like an immediate solution. Is it really possible that at the stage where WP is ... have an ALL CPT item in the nav menu is so complicate?

Comment: I've found this plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cpt-archive-to-nav/ - but it is no longer maintained and it doesn't work. The code is straight forward, but recent changes in WP may have broke down the compatibility.

Comment: Sorry for only coming back to you now. Unfortunately only pages get added automatically to the default nav menu. Categories and archieves needs to be added manually via a custom menu or as I suggested via a custom page template, or custom functions like a custom walker. There is just at this stage no default function to add categories and archives to the default nav menu