# Custom taxonomy archive templates not found

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom taxonomy register as the code below, but it does not find the taxonomy-specialty.php  nor archive.php templates (page not found error).

I did following (as recommended by other threads found on SE and the web):
- re-save the permalinks
- find the taxonomy settings page in wp-admin and when I hover over 'View' it points me to 'mysite.com/events/specialties/footology' for a 'Footology' taxonomy entry I created for a post of type 'event' - so the URL is as expected. However when visiting the link still get page not found error.

```
$specialty_args = array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Specialty',
                'singular_name' => 'Specialty',
                'search_items' => 'Search specialties',
                'all_items' => 'All specialties',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit specialty',
                'update_item' => 'Update specialty',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add new specialty',
                'new_item_name' => 'New specialty name',
                'menu_name' => 'Specialties',
            ),

            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => 'specialty',

            // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'events/specialties', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/specialties/"
                'hierarchical' => false
            ),
        );

        register_taxonomy('specialty', 'event', $specialty_args);
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type('specialty', 'event'); //says in https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy under 'Usage' to do this
```

I don't know what is wrong. Help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: do you register your taxonomy on the `init` action? are there posts assigned to the term you are viewing? what is your post type's URL structure and is it hierarchical? `var_dump($wp_query)` in the 404 template and look at what WordPress is querying for.

Comment: You are not very specific, but I think you are having [this problem](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166220/31545)

Answer (score 1):

The page not found error doesn't mean that the template file is not found/used. Note that a URL returns a 404 status header (not found), then 404.php is used (or index.php if 404.php doesn't exist).

I think your real problem is that you have not flushed the rewrite rules after the taxonomy has been registered. To do it, follow these steps:

**Manually**: go to settings->permalinks and click the save button (you don't need to change anything, just click the save button).

**Auto**: in your plugin, use `flush_rewrite_rules()` during plugin activation hook (never use `flush_rewrite_rules()` on every page load). For example:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_plugin_activation' );
function cyb_plugin_activation() {

    cyb_register_taxonomy();
    flush_rewrite_rules();

}

add_action( 'init', 'cyb_register_taxonomy' );
function cyb_register_taxonomy() {

    $specialty_args = array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Specialty',
                'singular_name' => 'Specialty',
                'search_items' => 'Search specialties',
                'all_items' => 'All specialties',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit specialty',
                'update_item' => 'Update specialty',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add new specialty',
                'new_item_name' => 'New specialty name',
                'menu_name' => 'Specialties',
            ),

            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => 'specialty',

            // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'events/specialty', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term (renamed to specialty from specialties)
                'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/specialties/"
                'hierarchical' => false
            ),
        );

        register_taxonomy('specialty', 'event', $specialty_args);
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type('specialty', 'event');

}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_plugin_deactivation' );
function cyb_plugin_deactivation() {

    // Flush the rewrite rules also on deactivation
    flush_rewrite_rules();

}
```

Comment: I did the flush of rewrite rules but still not working. The text on the page loaded ( {domain}/events/specialty/footology )is what I put into the 404.php template ... totally stumped on this :-(

Comment: I've tried the code I posted and it works perfectly. I can not say why it is not working for you without more information. Also, I would like to know why you have edited my answer to change the rewrite slug. I copied it from your question and it was (and still is in your question) `'slug' => 'events/specialties',`. Anyway, I've tested the code with both slugs, `events/specialties` and `events/specialty`, and both work correctly. Can you provide more informatioin? For example the code that you are using to register the `events` post type could be useful.

Answer (score -2):

```
'show_ui'           => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'query_var'         => 'specialty',
'has_archive'       => true, //make sure you have added this one
```

What is your archive name? What is your archive url? Actually, your archive file name should be like that archive-specialty.php, your post type archive url will be like this yourdomain.com/events/specialties. I have tested, it should work on yours.

If you are not sure about custom post type, use [wordpress type plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) or use [wordpress generator](https://generatewp.com/post-type/)

Comment: I think you have mixed taxonomies and custom post types: `has_archive` is not a valid argument for taxonomies (see [register_taxonomy() docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)) and `archive-{taxonomyname}.php` is not a valid taxnomy template file (see [tempalte hierarchy in WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)). Note that the question is about taxonomies, not custom post types.